# Receive and print string array object over socket

Tags: java, arrays, sockets

Recently I am making a server-client program using multithread concept. For some reason, I have to sent an array of string from client to server. I am using `ObjectOutputStream` and `writeObject()` method to send that array of string. For example I have an array named `String data[] = new String[3]` then I send it over `socketwriteobject(data)`.

Question is, how do I receive this array of string on server? Is it `ObjectInputStream` and this method `readObject()` can help me? I just want to iterate this object and make it into new array of string in server side. For example `String newData[] = new String[3]` and then put the string in `data[0]` into `newData[0]` until `data[2]` into `newData[2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe when you read your object using `readObject()`, it should return your String[] itself.

```
            String[] myObjects = (String[])inObjectStream.readObject();
```

Is that not working?

Comment: Yep, its work! thank you. But i have a question, why we must put a `try-catch` in the block of this code?

Comment: Since `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` throws some exceptions for some possible failures e.g. `ClassNotFoundException` - Class of a serialized object cannot be found.
`InvalidClassException` - Something is wrong with a class used by serialization.
`StreamCorruptedException` - Control information in the stream is inconsistent.
`OptionalDataException` - Primitive data was found in the stream instead of objects.
`IOException` - Any of the usual Input/Output related exceptions.

Comment: If any of the above scenarios arise, i.e. its unable to read the file, it will throw `IOException`, which you need to handle in catch block. `If you don't want to add try/cath, add the above mentioned exceptions as `throws IOException, OptionalDataException, InvalidClassException , ClassNotFoundException , StreamCorruptedException` towards the end of of your method signature. Please let me know, if you need  any help in doing that.